# Automate set color cell- based on hex color code in other column in Excel

Tags: excel, automation, colors, formatting, spreadsheet

I have a column in excel with color codes like:

```
#98BF64
#D9B300
#FF6347
#118DFF
#D9B300
#DEEFFF
#FF7F48
#000000
#00334E
#B3B0AD
```

And I want each color code to be the fill color of the next column in my spread sheet.

[image: sample]

I am doing this by hand formatting the fill cell with each custom color code in hex option.

I have a long list and I am looking for ways to make this fast, is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score -1):

Not quite what I was looking for but it makes the trick. I found a code that formats the cell with the hex number of the cell when written on it. So I took the # number with =right(a1;1) and then erase the formula after it was formatted. Easy! Find the code here:

https://coderedirect.com/questions/593903/set-an-automatic-color-background-depending-on-the-hex-value-in-the-cell